# Laravel queues, get parameter from controller

Tags: laravel, queue, sendmail

I'm working with Laravel queue, my problem is that I don't get the parameter passed from the controller. This is my code:

**Jobs**

```php
protected $id;

public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function handle()
{    
    Log::info($this->id);
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function getAccept($id)
{
    $job = (new SendQueueMail($id))->delay(10);
    $this->dispatch($job);
}
```

I tried the dd() function but still receive $id. When I run the queue above I don't get $id.

**laravel.log**

> [2019-04-19 09:54:22] local.INFO:

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: I solved the problem with a command: `php artisan queue:restart`. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
use App\Jobs\SendQueueMail;

public function getAccept($id){

SendQueueMail::dispatch($id)
                ->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));

}
```

Use this may help you

Comment: I did try your way but it still doesn't get the $id

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
public function getAccept($id)
{
    dispatch(new SendQueueMail($id));
}
```

Comment: I did try your way but it still doesn't get the $id

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correct just update you controller with below code

```
public function getAccept($id)
{
    $this->dispatch(new test($id))->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem with a command: `php artisan queue:restart`. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Good to know :)